# Microsoft Access: create subdatasheet with SQL command?

Tags: ms-access

Microsoft Access supports "[subdatasheets](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-a-subdatasheet-900d1d30-5ea2-4e47-80a7-ddcb87a53d14)"

[image]

Is it possible to create this type of table from a SQL command? Or does one have to manually point and click to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL commands can run scripts/manipulate data and organize it. It's a declarative language. What you're referring to is part of Access' UI features/capabilities.

Your subdatasheet link shows an `Orders` table with a 1:M relationship to an `Order Details` table. One Order record with many details about that Order.

The reference you linked shows you how to set this up; it doesn't take any SQL or even VBA to do this. This is a way to view data and it's correlated data from another table in a `Datasheet` view.

Comment: Thank you -- I was hoping there would be some programmatic way to create a nested table as we need to do this same operation for several databases.

Comment: Ah.. I see. Unfortunately there's no script you could write to do this. Fortunately, it only takes a few steps! I'm optimistic you could knock it out fairly quickly.